# MVC ModelSate.isValid always true when posting from ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, model-view-controller, modelstate

There are many similar posts to mine, but none has the exact issue I am having...

My requirements is to prompt the user to enter first & last name about persons in a list as many as the user wants. 
The first time the view loads, it shows one empty form. The user fills it and then if needs to, asks to load data about the next person and so on. The user fills data about one person at a time, before loading another the next one. If tries to, the default validation stops him from doing so until all fields are complete.

So, I have two submit buttons with the same name but different values, one to request the next portion by ajax and add it to the list in the model and the other to complete the request. The httpost method, based on the name of the button, decides which action to take (add more or finalize transaction).

But I have a problem, when I call my httppost action method in my controller via json, the model binding is not behaving correctly; therefore, the ModelState.IsValid always equals true even if I leave off the fields empty.

My form in the view has a div with contents such as:

```
    <div>
        <label for="FirstName">First Name</label>
        <div>
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Persons[i].FirstName)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Persons[i].FirstName)
        </div>
    </div>

    <div>
        <label for="LastName">Last Name</label>
        <div>
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Persons[i].LastName)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Persons[i].LastName)
        </div>
    </div>
```

and I have these two buttons that both do submit:

```
        <button type="submit" name="actionType" value="AddPerson"  onclick="addPerson();">Add Another</button>
        <button type="submit" name="actionType" value="Done">Done</button>
```

my model look like this:

```
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "First Name is required.")]
    [Display(Name = "First Name")]
    public String FirstName { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Last Name is required.")]
    [Display(Name = "Last Name")]
    public String LastName { get; set; }
```

and my post method:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddPersonMethod(MyModel mm, string actionType)
{
    if (actionType.Equals("AddPerson"))
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            // add item to the list in the model
        }
    }
    return View(mm);
}
```

I tried setting ajax against the first button:

```
function addPerson()
{
    $.ajax({
        url: "myurl",
        type: "POST",
        data: { actionType: 'AddPerson' },
        success: function () {
            console.log('ajax succeeded');
        }
    });
}
```

This will do the proper validation against required but continues to the httppost in the controller (it should stop since the validation is wrong) in the controller with ModelState.IsValid = true. 
How do I make it stop when wrong inputs are entered? And when it gets to post method with ajax to have that ModelState.IsValid properly set to false!?

FYI: My jquery.validate.js and jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js are already loaded in my code.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the reason is mainly because I didn't include this in the data of the ajax call:

```
$form.serialize()
```

My ajax after that still needed to be tweaked further. Here is a good example of a perfect ajax call with useful comments:
http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/289820/Post-a-form-using-Ajax-instead-of-Normal-Post

my initiating button didn't have to be wired to an event, it could be as simple as:

```
<input type="submit" name="actionType" value="AddPerson" />
```